# Sublimetext 3 PHP variable name to be inserted with $ sign

Tags: php, variables, sublimetext3

When I write variable name in Sublime 3 in PHP language it does find it in the code and offers to select it from popup window (autocompletion or something) but upon selecting it inserts variable name WITHOUT dollar sign ($) which is **VERY annoying**, because I need navigate back manually to type it out...

Is there anyway to append dollar sign automatically (prior variable name) upon selection variable name from autocompletion window?

[image: dollar sign is not appended after picking from popup]

desired behavior:
**$varname** to be insertes (together with $ sign)

Comment: well , there is the same issue,,, and even it does not offer varname if you didn't put $ as a first character...

Comment: Oh sorry for that advice. I always used PHPStorm for PHP code, and then switched to JS and VSCode, so never tried PHP there. PHPStorm is great.

Comment: Used PHPstorm in past as well, that is why I am missing this "feature"